# Can the same surface have minimal genus in both a 3-manifold and a 4-manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, surfaces, foliations

By a *surface of minimal genus* I mean in it's homology class: A surface $S_0$ embedded in a smooth manifold $M$ such that any other surface $S$ with $[S]=[S_0]\in H_2(M)$, we have $g(S)\geq g(S_0)$.

So my question is: If I have a surface $S$ of minimal genus in a smooth 3-manifold $N$ which is a submanifold of a smooth 4-dimensional manifold $M$, is $S$ also minimal in $M$?

I am vaguely aware of "the minimal surface problem" in 4-manifolds, and how the existence of a taut foliaton (with leaves that are minimal sufaces) in $N$ could be used to bound the genus (or Euler characteristic) of surfaces in $M$, but I think since I'm talking about the same surface in both $N$ and $M$, this might just be a topological question, rather than some complicated Seiberg-Witten thing.

Comment: You're going to want to say something that sounds like $N$ being minimally embedded in $M$. Otherwise, try this: pick a sufficiently complicated 3-manifold that embeds into $S^4$, and a homology class whose minimal genus surface has high genus. Now embed this 3-fold into $S^4$ - your complicated high genus surface certainly is not minimal for the trivial homology class. (I think you can do something similar even if you specify that the 3-fold embedding represents a nontrivial homology class, or that the surface does after embedding, etc)

Comment: But the surface is minimum in it's homology class, which would presumably not be the trivial class in $M$ if it's not the trivial class in $N$, right?

Comment: The presumption in your comment is incorrect. The homology homomorphism $H_2(N) \to H_2(M)$ induced by the inclusion map $N \hookrightarrow M$ can easily have nontrivial kernel. In fact in the comment of @MikeMiller the kernel of $H_2(N) \to H_2(M)=H_2(S^4)$ is the whole of $H_2(N)$, because the target is the trivial group.